# C# WPF - Resizable Usercontrol / Page (Grab and drag resizing)

Tags: c#, wpf, window-resize

How do you make a user-resizable user control in WPF?

For example, in Visual Studio the user can resize their panels, like the Solution Explorer. How can I make my page be resizable?

I know that making a grid splitter is a solution, but any other solution besides that? Also will it take into account the other pages in the main window and resize them accordingly as well?

And how do I set a maximum horizontal resize limit?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this effect with a [SplitContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/splitcontainer-control-windows-forms)

Comment: Is it content aware? Would the other panels resize accordingly?

Comment: @KrustoStoianov it depends on how you use the "Anchor" and/or "Dock" under "Layout"